# Why does sed only show one line though pipe

Tags: unix, sed

I have several txt files under a directory, and I want see first line of every file

So I use

```
ls *txt | xargs sed -n '1p'
```

however it only returns one line of the first file

What is wrong?

P.S.: I know I can use `head`, but what I ask is why `sed` is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the argument -t to xargs to see what is going on:

```
ls *txt | xargs -t sed -n '1p'
```

You will see that sed is run as:

```
sed -n '1p' foo.txt bar.txt gar.txt
```

and as sed only supports one input file, it will print the first line of 
the file foo.txt and exit.

xargs is assuming you want to pass the list of input files all together.

To tell it to pass one at a time, you need to use the -L NUM option,
which tells xargs to pass one line at a time from your ls command.
[Note there are other issues you will run into if any file name has a blank in it]

```
ls *txt | xargs -L 1 -t sed -n '1p'
```

You will see:

```
sed -n '1p' foo.txt 
sed -n '1p' bar.txt 
sed -n '1p' gar.txt
```

In unix there are many ways to do any task; other ways include:

(if you use /bin/csh or /bin/tcsh):

```
foreach f (*txt)
echo -n $f:
sed -1p $f
end
```

If you use /bin/sh or /bin/ksh, then:

```
for files in *txt; 
do 
echo -n $files :
sed -n '1p' $files
done
```

Also consider using the program find; it lets you qualify the types of files you want to look at and can recursively examine sub directories:

```
`find . -type f -a -name "*txt" -print -a -exec sed -n '1p' {} \;`
```

Comment: quote your variables,

Comment: `sed` does support multiple files, but (unless `-i`) as John said it treats them all as one stream so `1p` is the first line from the first file.

Comment: There are so many good answers. But I finally decide to accept yours. Because you explained more details on the pipe and xargs things. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First, `ls` and `xargs` are not useful here.  Please read: ["Don't Parse ls"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  For a more reliable form of the command that works with all kinds of file names, use:

```
sed -n '1p' *.txt
```

Second, `sed` treats its input files all as one stream.  So, the above does *not* do what you want.  Use `head` instead (as you said):

```
head -n1 *.txt
```

To suppress the verbose headers that `head` prints and make the output more like `sed 1p`, use the `-q` option:

```
head -qn1 *.txt
```

#### Handling many many files

If you have many many `.txt` files, where, depending on system configuration, "many" likely means several tens of thousands of such files, then another approach is needed.  `find` is useful:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -exec head -n1 {} +
```

Comment: @hek2mgl Also, given that the OP's goal seems to be to learn new tools, what was your concern over awk?  If efficiency was important, then `gawk 'FNR==1{print; nextfile;}' *.txt`.

Comment: I have zero concerns about `awk`. But `head` is simply the way to go here (imo). I simply think it is much cleaner to use `head` for what it is meant for. `awk` has sooo many domains of usefulness, let's keep one for good old `head`. :)

Comment: Thank you, John1024. `-q` is really handy!

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -s '1!d' file1 file2 file...
```

This will print the first line of each file i.e. delete all lines but the first of each file.

Comment: Or `sed -sn '1p' *.txt`.  _+1 for finding the `-s` flag_: this is what the OP needed.

Comment: great `-s` option ! Thank you